# Scrapy: Continuously scrape certain link pattern without repetition

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following link pattern: https://www.somewebsite.com/api-internal/v1/festivals/1/ at the end where is currently `/1/` that's the pk. My goal is to scrape weekly every pk of that API. Currently, there are 100 entries, next week it might be 110.

Is there a way to scrape this week the first 100 and next week the "new" 10 entries, without scraping the old 100 entries I already did?

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "pk": 1,
    "name": "Stop Making Sense",
    "theme": "purple",
    "slug": "stop-making-sense",
    "series": {
        "pk": 9,
        "name": "Stop Making Sense",
        "slug": "stop-making-sense"
    },
    "edition": "2012",
    "is_active": false,
    "featured": false,
    "listed": false,
    "start": "2012-08-02",
    "end": "2012-08-06",
    "date_unconfirmed": false,
    "url": "https://www.somewebsite.com/entries/stop-making-sense/2012/"
}
```

Comment: You have to use a table (naive) or a database(better) with a field "pk", and check for the latest pk in your DB every time you run the program and start scraping from that.

Comment: Ah okay, interesting, so I would e.g. use DynamoDB and save the latest pk in there. And how would you check that I reached the "last" pk? There are several cases where pk's are skipped. For example 57, 58 doesn't exist, but pk 59 exists again. Probably, because some entries were being deleted.

Comment: you could save the state of each passing PK too. Either any of them had an error or not, but from my PoV it doesn't matter if you had skipped them before since after getting deleted a new PK will probably not get the number of a previously deleted one, so you're OK to go after the last saved PK probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of options to don't load previously scraped is usage of scrapy [`HttpCacheMiddleware`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware) 


scrapy HttpCacheMiddleware stores each request and response in local folder so on next scraper run - scraper will download responses only for new urls (for previously scraped pages - responses from local 'httpcahce' will be used)


To completely skip previously scraped results we can add conditional statement and check response for `download_latency` meta key (responses from `httpcache` don't have it). As result Spider will return items from new urls only.

As You can't know how many ids website will have in future. There is option to start from id `1` and continiously increasing it during process in `parse` method instead of populating `start_urls` list with something like `[f".../{str(id)}" for id in range(1,100)]`

 If on some point (for example during processing id - 110) - application return 404 - request for url with id 111 - will not be scheduled.

 Result will be something like this:

```
import scrapy
import json

class SomeApiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "api"
    custom_settings = {"HTTPCACHE_ENABLED": True }
    start_urls = ['https://www.somewebsite.com/api-internal/v1/festivals/1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        id = str(int(response.url.split("/")[-2]) + 1)   # get next id number
        if "download_latency" in response.meta.keys():
            data = json,loads(response.body)
            ...   # do your stuff
        yield scrapy.Request(url = f"https://www.somewebsite.com/api-internal/v1/festivals/{id}/",
            callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thank you Georgiy. Do you know the difference between `scrapy.Request` and `response.follow`?